# Android putting parcelable in bundle raises type mismatch

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, parcel

I am trying to put a parcelable in a bundle that I want to send to a navigation component. My data class is,

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Post(
    val name: String,

    val slug: String,

    val thumbnail:String
) : Parcelable
```

#### navigation

```
<argument
    android:name="post"
    app:argType="com.example.blog.models.Post"
    app:nullable="true" />
```

#### viewmodel variable

```
val post: MutableLiveData<List<Post>> by lazy { MutableLiveData<List<Post>>() }

// after api call, the body of the response which is a list of Post objects
// are attached to viewmodel.

post.postValue(response.body())
```

#### fragment

```
// after observing the changes in the post variable in viewmodel,
// a bundle is created which is added to the navigation.. 

val bundle =  Bundle()
bundle.putParcelable("post", post.value)
```

#### errors

Editor

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Parcelable?
Found: List<Post>?
```

Build

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Post>? but Parcelable? was expected
```

Comment: Do you want to add full array of posts in bundle or just one post in bundle?

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan full array of posts

Comment: Alright then the way you are using to send data in intent is for only a single object post.

Comment: I am writing answer please review in a while.

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan i hope `app:argType="com.example.blog.models.Post[]"` makes it work..

Comment: Awesome. Thats great

Comment: still i cant solve the type mismatch

Comment: Are you getting same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs of all you need to use LiveData which will wrap your MutableLiveData.

```
 fun getPosts(): LiveData<List<Post>> {
        return post
    }
```

What you want to pass to your Bundle is the List directly, but wrapped in a Serialized implementation of List. That's why the code below wraps the value of your LiveData in an ArrayList.

So, you can do this instead:

```
  bundle.putParcelableArrayList("post", arrayListOf(getPosts().value));
```

To read it back:

```
bundle.getParcelableArrayList("post") as List<Post>?
```

Comment: I am trying to use parcelable not serializable.

Comment: I have not tried yet but you can also try by adding Mutable data directly into parcelablearraylist instead of converting it into liveData. Thanks

Comment: well I have changed the variable to `ArrayList` in viewmodel.. and API call..  so `arrayListOf()`  part can be omited. Thanks

Comment: Alright. Thanks for information. Feels great to work with you :)